# how to use regex or other ways to remove extra '\r\n' in java string

Tags: java, string

I have a String like this:

```
String orginal = "this is for test hello\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" +
    "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nhello" + 
    "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nhello";
```

The user press 'enter' a lot of time when input content in text area, so in java, it change to a lot of '\r\n'.
I want to change it to:

```
String newStr = "this is for test hello\r\nhello\r\nhello"
```

How can I keep only one `\r\n`

Comment: Does the string come from a `JTextArea`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ought to do it...

```
String newStr = original.replaceAll("(\r\n)+", "\r\n");
```

You might also want to consider using the `line.separator` system property instead of hard coding `\r\n`, since this may be different on other platforms. For instance Unix just uses a single line feed `\n`. This would be more portable...

```
final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String newStr = original.replaceAll("(" + NEWLINE + ")+", NEWLINE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution (LF - UNIX, CR- Mac, CRLF - Windows) could be like this

```
String newStr = original.replaceAll("(\r\n|\r|\n)+", "$1");
```